# How to make LLM response faster ( Langchain )?

Tags: chatbot, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

i am using langchain for creating llm in python. Using load_qa_chain() with chain_type="stuff" and temperature 0.
The responses are not fast enough. Some people want me to using Steaming=True but it raises 2 problems:

1. Can't get number of tokens used when using Streaming=True.
2. Can't send streaming data back to frontend. Code only returns one single response and not stream the response back to frontend.

So is there any other way to make LLM give faster responses. ??

I was hoping the LLM could give faster responses